Chromebook kiosk app don't open hyperlinks
How can I modify the Google admin policy for kiosk so my kiosk app opens other hyperlinks on the main window app?
I modified my manifest 1000 times already. And nothing
I looked at some similar kiosk app and Still can't open other links on the main window. Is this possible? And what software dp you all recommend to use?
